# How do I replace an item in an array in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList, initialized as follows:

```
    public static List<int[]> items = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

I add items to it like this:

```
    items.add(new int[] {2,0,1,0,1});
```

Can I change a specific entry on an array already on the ArrayList (for example: the 2 at index 0), or do I have to recreate the array every time with `items.set()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
int[] array = items.get(0);
array[0] = <new value>;
```

Comment: I know. Writing it in two lines to make it explicit for OP how this works.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you.